# Can we have multiple foreign key in active record schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have an schema that has person table, email table, phone table and address table.

Person model

```
class Person< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :emails, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Email Model

```
class Email< ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Person
  has_one :phone, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :address, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Phone Model

```
class Phone< ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Email
end
```

Address Model

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :Email
   end
```

My schema looks like this

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_06_03_231058) do

  create_table "emails", id: :string, limit: 36, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.string "Person_id", limit: 36
    t.index ["Person_id", "created_at"], name: "index_email_on_Person_id_and_created_at"
  end

  create_table "phones", id: :string, limit: 36, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone_id", limit: 36, null: false
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.string "email_id", limit: 36
    t.string "person_id", limit: 36
    t.index ["email_id", "created_at"], name: "index_phone_on_email_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "fk_rails_7119a1d90f"
  end

  create_table "persons", id: :string, limit: 36, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_persons_on_created_at"
  end

  create_table "address", id: :string, limit: 36, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "address_id", limit: 36, null: false
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 3, null: false
    t.string "email_id", limit: 36
    t.string "person_id", limit: 36
    t.index ["email_id", "created_at"], name: "index_address_on_email_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "fk_rails_485c78b376"
  end

  add_foreign_key "emails", "persons"
  add_foreign_key "phones", "emails"
  add_foreign_key "phones", "persons"
  add_foreign_key "address", "emails"
  add_foreign_key "address", "persons"
end
```

So if you notice in my schema at very end I have 2 foreign keys for phones and address.

when I insert data email_id is placed in person table but not person_id.
I see same issue in address table as well where email_id is placed but not person_id

I am new to rails Active record concept when through online documentation couldn't really solve this issue any help is much appreciated.

Comment: FYI- if you wonder why in world I have person as foreign key in address and phone table, this is due to some validation constraint I have to meet.

Comment: You actually can, you just need to let attribute_id optional and alternate between them, but look, your design looks a little bit weird, I'd suggest you to relate your tables only with person_id and through a person, you can get their emails, phones and whatever other info you need.

Comment: @WenderFreese Thank you for response, not really sure what you mean by making attribute_id optional? which id are you referring to? person_id? being optional in phone and address table?

Comment: @WenderFreese My schema is little odd due to constraints that we have to create in order to avoid duplicates

Comment: It seemed to me at a glance that you would have or person_id or email_id in `address` table, for example, if it would the case you'd need to make them optional to because sometimes one of them would be `nil`.

Comment: I don't have too much context to suggest an approach but It seems you need to manage `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the other models if you are creating them in different moments or receive the parameters, create a transaction and instantiate/create each model separately before creating its relation.